# "Arial Italic" font not working in JS canvas

Tags: javascript, fonts, html5-canvas

```
ctx.font = "50px Arial Italic";
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillText("Hello World!", 150, 120);
```

When I use this, the text is shown in the default font (which I assume is Times New Roman). When I try other fonts, such as Arial or Arial Black, it works perfectly.

Comment: It's `"Italic 50px Arial"`. From [CSS font](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font): "font-style, font-variant and font-weight must precede font-size"

Comment: Thanks, that works. Arial Italic is supposed to be a different font though.

Comment: If it's meant to be the font name, you'll have to quote it: `ctx.font = '50px "Arial Italic"';`. But I don't think that's a well-known generic font family, you'll probably have to load a custom font.